# Coloring output different in MOTD and run-parts

Tags: ubuntu, colors

Trying to color my command output, I am stuck in understanding the difference between

- logging into my machine and seeing the MOTD
- running run-parts on /etc/update-motd.d/

I created this test-script to illustrate:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
W="\e[0;39m"
R="\e[1;31m"
G="\e[1;32m"
echo -e "This is a test for ${G}GREEN${W} and ${R}RED${W}"
echo -e "Lets highlight some colors aight?" | grep --color 'ight'
```

When I run it directly, both lines have colors.

```
root@server:/etc/update-motd.d# ./test-file
```

When I run it via run-parts, both lines have colors.

```
root@server:/etc/update-motd.d# run-parts ./
```

**BUT** when I log in, only the first line gets colored!

How can I have colored greps or even debug this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you log in there is no `run-parts /etc/update-motd.d`. The `run-parts` happens from time to time, **non-interactively**, to update `/etc/motd`.

By default `grep` doesn't show colors when running non-interactively (for good reason). You may try `grep --color=always`, possibly `TERM=xterm grep --color=always`.

Use [`sudo update-motd`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/update-motd.8.html)(8) to update `/etc/motd` immediately and see the updated file.

Comment: Thanks, that helped perfectly. The issue was me using --color instead of --color=always.